# Footer not appearing on resume

Tags: header-footer, cv, resume

I have been having trouble displaying a footer in my resume. Here are the links to the `.cls` file and the `.tex` file respectively.

**`.cls` file**
[resume.cls file](http://pastebin.com/eEzxx2at)

**`.tex` file**
[resume.tex file](http://pastebin.com/tvXszpax)

Sorry for the links to pastebin, but the `.cls` file was so long, that I figured copy and pasting it here would be unsightly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `resume` class doesn't expect header or footers to be used. Querying for the default values values of `\textheight`, `\paperheight` and `\footskip` in the resume class:

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{resume}

\begin{document}

\begin{resume}
The value for \verb+\textheight+ is \the\textheight.

The value for \verb+\paperheight+ is \the\paperheight.

The value for \verb+\footskip+ is \the\footskip.
\end{resume}

\end{document}
```

one gets:

[image]

And one has that `\textheight+\footskip>\paperheight`, so the footer will be typeset outside the physical page. To prevent this, reassign values to `\textheight` (and maybe `\footskip`); for example:

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{resume}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\textheight=10in
\footskip=25pt

\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % no line in header area
\fancyfoot[C]{\today} % other info in "inner" position of footer line
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\begin{resume}
text
\end{resume}

\end{document}
```

Some remarks not related to the problem: the `resume` class seems somehow "old"; perhaps you could consider using a more modern approach; in particular, the class (and also your document) uses the obsolete two-letter font switches (`\bf`, `\sc`,...); you should use the proper switches instead (`\bfseries`, `\scshape`,...).